# Generalised additive model: What is ref.df in R's output?

Tags: model, generalized-additive-model, degrees-of-freedom

Hi I am struggling to understand Ref.df in the output screen in R:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
               edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(meangrain) 1.779  2.209 3.193  0.0451 *
s(depth)     2.108  2.697 3.538  0.0254 *
```

What does it mean and is it necessary to include this term for presenting results of GAM in a paper? Is it giving us information necessary for prediction?

Comment: Also would like to know this. I've searched the net but cant find an explicit answer.
Is it possibly just the residual df under a different label?

Answer (score 5):

Simon Wood, the author of the `mgcv` package and a book on GAMs, explains this [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2019-March/462135.html):

> These [Ref.df] are a bit of a throwback really, and are not very useful - they
> are reference degrees of freedom used in computing test statistic and
> the p-values, but since the null distributions are non-standard the
> reference DoF is not very interpretable.